# Wikipedia deletion log download

Tags: java, python, dump, wikipedia, information-retrieval

I need wikipedia deletion log for my project. I was able to find deletion logs here

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Log&type=delete&user=&page=&year=&month=-1&tagfilter=&hide_review_log=1
```

I can download 5000 entries at a time, but it will take lot of time, due to large number of pages. Is there a dump available?

Thank you
Bala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not ask at Wikipedia? There are various dumps available, including tools on the toolserver that may be of use. Your best bet is asking at [the technical pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aVPT).

Comment: Downvoting without explaining why is not very helpful.